# Powerpoint 2016: format shape with keyboard commands

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

In ppt 2010, I used to be able to do the following to use the format shape options, using the example of changing the left margin of the text box of the currently selected shape:

Right-click (mapped to a keybaord key) -> O (format shape) -> T (text box) -> Alt+L (left margin) -> arrows (increase / decrease) -> enter (accept & close)

It sounds like a lot, but I use this 10x per day, and it goes really fast. With ppt 2016, there's this task pane window that pops up on the right, which doesn't accept keyboard commands.

Is there any way to change 'format shape' options using the keyboard? Or has Microsoft completely prioritized prettiness over efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a shortcut in the Quick Access Toolbar such as "Size" or any of the other items that fall under "Format Shape" it will bring up the task pane window to the right and you can use keyboard shortcuts (tab, left, right, etc.).

However, the issue is that the task pane window doesn't close and if it remains open and you then try to repeat the process I describe above, it will not respond to keyboard shortcuts. Quite frustrating, but it is what it is